# React Component is blank in the webpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I created a Reactjs app by [create-react-app](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/).

... but the components are not shown in the page, I think it is probably because App.js is not rendering the components?

Here is my code:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import login from "./containers/login/login";
class App extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                    <div className="App">
                            <login/>
                    </div>
            );
        }
}
export default App;
```

/containers/login/login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "./login.css";

class login extends Component {
        render() {
                return (
                        <div className="headings">
                                <form action="">
                                Username <br/>
                                <input type="text" name="userrname" />
                                <br/>
                                Password <br/>
                                <input type="password" name="password" />
                                <br/>
                                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
                                </form>
                        </div>
                );
        }
}
export default login;
```

The component in the browser is like this:

```
<login></login>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your own component need to start with a capital letter, or [Babel will treat them as strings](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwGw9g5glgdg9APiA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.3.4).

Rename the variable to `Login` and it will work.

```
import Login from "./containers/login/login";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Login />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```